# Tiles in the Tilemap dont overlap properly

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap, tiles

This is my first try making a "proper" game in Unity. I'm using the latest version (2019.2.2 at the time of writing) and I'm writing with C#. This is a project I'm doing for my studies, together with another person (he makes tiles, sound, music and I'm at charge of the programming).

We are making a 2D Roguelike RPG using the Unity tilemap feature.

My algorithm to generate dungeons works really well, but only used one ground tile and one wall tile. We found that to be very boring and changed it.

Now comes the problem. If I let the algorithm pick between fewer than 3 tiles, everything works fine.

[image: Example of how it should work]

If I let the algorithm pick from more than 2 tiles, something strange happens and the some tiles don't overlap properly.

[image: Example of how It shouldn't work]

I hope somebody can help me understand why this happens.

Here the important settings of camera and tilemap:

1. Camera 
    [image: Settings of the camera]
2. Grid 
    [image: Settings of the grid]
3. GroundLayer 
    [image: Settings of the First Tilemap]
4. WallLayer 
    [image: Settings of the Second Tilemap]

One weird think I have been able to find out: The tiles that don't overlap will change if I change the position of the camera.

As a gif:

[image: Zooming into the map, the dark, incorrectly-overlapped walls occur in different positions]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your wall tile sprites extend beyond the bounds of the square tile they represent, and up into the space occupied by the tile above, and you're relying on these tiles to be drawn later than/over the tile above to get the appearance that you want? If so, this probably isn't a code issue (and posting all your code is not an appropriate use of this site anyway) - what you should walk us through instead is your [configuration of your tilemap's rendering mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Isometric-RenderModes.html) and packing settings on your sprites.

Comment: @DMGregory Should I remove the code then? Sry for posting It then. Yes, the walltiles are 32x64 and reach over the tile above them. The ground tiles are 32x32

Comment: Up to you - it's does not look like it's required to solve this problem, so I'd say it distracts from the question. Generally we ask users to do the work of boiling their problem down to a "minimal complete verifiable example" - the least code & scene/project setup instructions we'd need to reproduce the problem in a new project. So if your dungeon generator algorithm isn't the problem, we don't need that code. You can reproduce the same problem by painting with these tiles on a tilemap with no scripts at all.

Comment: Made the changed, removed the code so the post dont gets to hugh.

Comment: I see you're rendering in chunk mode. Did you try packing your sprites into an atlas as recommended at the link I posted above, and testing the result in play mode?

Comment: I will try. Can I still use the tiles the same way and drag them into Tileset Array? (see first or second picture on the right side)

Comment: Have you observed any evidence to the contrary? This sounds like something you can answer through your own testing.

Comment: I thought after I added the sprites to the atlas, I need to get them from there... but I was wrong. It works now perfectly :D

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer. In future, I recommend reading the documentation for the Unity features you're using thoroughly — they're imperfect, but they show how to solve a lot of the most common issues like this.

Comment: hey, random comment, I think that your second selection of tiles for the walls is too dark, I think it should be a little lighter so there's not so much contrast.  Like what your doing so far.

Answer (score 1):

"Pack all the individual Sprites that make up the Tilemap into a single Sprite Atlas to solve this issue. To do this:

1. Create a Sprite Atlas from the Assets menu (go to: Atlas > Create > Sprite Atlas).
2. Add the Sprites to the Sprite Atlas by dragging them to the Objects for Packing list in the Atlas’ Inspector window.
3. Click Pack Preview. Unity packs the Sprites into the Sprite Atlas during Play mode, and correctly sorts and renders them. This is only visible in the Editor during Play"

This solved my problem.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tilemap-Isometric-RenderModes.html